# Removing the word "Pages -" from the Home page Title

Tags: title

We have our website [G20.org](https://www.g20.org), we are trying to remove the "Pages -" word that appears on the page title.

Comment: Could you Please add a snapshot of what you are trying to remove?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/w8nVXjq.png
https://i.imgur.com/Ia9VgAL.png

Comment: Note: The word "Pages -" is added automatically when we change the page title inside the Sharepoint.